# C++ read and edit jpg file using ifstream

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm trying to work on a simple image encryption project and I have a few questions I want to ask.

1. Should I store each byte of data from `ifstream` into a character like I did in my code?
2. Each byte printed is a weird symbol (which is correct), but why does adding 10(an `int`) to that always results in a number when printed?

   ```
   int main() {

       vector <char> data; // Stores each byte from image.jpg

       ifstream fileIn("image.jpg", ios::binary);

       int i = 0; // Used for accessing each item in data vector

       while (fileIn){

               //Add each character from the image file into the vector
               data.push_back(fileIn.get());

               cout <<  "Original: " << data[i] << endl; // Print each character from image.jgp

               cout << "Result after adding: " << data[i] + 10 << endl; // This line is where I need help with

               i++;

               system("pause");
       }

       fileIn.close();

       system("pause");
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Output:

```
Original:  å
Result after adding: -112

Original:  Æ
Result after adding: -100

Original:
Result after adding: 12
```

As you can see, adding 10 always results in a number. How do I increment these values correctly so that I can change it back later?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just for clarification, you are not actually doing anything to the actual JPEG image data? It just happens to be that your input file is a JPEG image file?

Answer (score 3):

When you do an arithmetic operation (like addition) with a value of a type that is smaller than `int` (like `char` in your case) then that value will be *promoted* to `int` and the operation is done using two `int` values.

So the expression `data[i] + 10` is equivalent to `static_cast<int>(data[i]) + 10`.

Read more about [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) and [arithmetic operator conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions).

---

As for how to solve your problem, first you have to make sure that the result of the operation actually fits in a `char`. What if the byte you have read is `127` and you add `10`? Then the result is out of bounds of a `signed char` (which seems to be what you have).

If the result is *not* out of bounds, then you can just cast it:

```
char result = static_cast<char>(data[i] + 10);
```

As a small side-note, if you're reading binary data you are not really reading *characters*, so I suggest using a [fixed-with integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) like `int8_t` or `uint8_t` instead of `char`. On supported platforms (which is just about all these days) they are just aliases for `signed char` and `unsigned char` (respectively) but using the aliases is more informative for the readers of your code.